# Returning max value in java

Tags: java, max, return-value, sliding-window

Pretty simple question I'm sure, since I'm only just learning.

In a larger class that I am on my way of implementing, we have to provide a method Max to return the maximum value in an array. This is what I have:

```
public static int Max(int[] window){
    //assume length of array window > 0

    int Max = window[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < window.length; i++){
        if (window[i] > Max) {
            Max = window[i];
        }
        return Max;
    }
}
```

However, the method does not compile. I believe it has something to do with the return type. The program calls up this function (and a similar Min function) like this further on in the program:

```
System.out.println("[" + window.Min() + " " + window.Max() + "]");
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Thanks for all of your answers! Just started learning coding, so trivial mistakes like this one can still cause a whole lot of frustration. Saving my ass, all of you!

Comment: What error does it give when it doesn't compile?  This is always key information.

Comment: What if length of `window` array is `1` (or even `0`)? Will your code enter loop (if not then how your method should return its result)? Also are you sure that `return max` should be called in each iteration?

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan @ Pshemo I'm implementing a sliding window class via arrays that should also give the maximum and the minimum value in the window. I am using Eclipse, which is currently telling me that "This method must return a result of type int." as well as a "dead code" warning at the beginning of the for loop. I'm pretty new to java (and coding in general) so I'm confused as to why it won't return max as an int.

Answer (score 3):

Java always considers the possibility of the `for` loop not being entered, and sees no `return` statement at the end of the method, giving a missing return statement compiler error.  The method is declared to return something, an `int`, so every possible execution path must return something.

Move `return Max;` after the end of the `for` loop, both to satisfy the compiler and to provide a correct "find the max" method.

Incidentally, Java variables usually have a lowercase first letter per normal conventions.  The `Max` variable should be called `max`.  The same applies to the name of the `Max` method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does not compile because there's a way you can get to the end of the method without an explicit `return` statement.

You need to put that `return Max;` at the bottom, as opposed to inside the `for` loop:

```
public static int Max(int[] window){
    //assume length of array window > 0

    int Max = window[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < window.length; i++){
        if (window[i] > Max) {
            Max = window[i];
        }

    }
    return Max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement should not be in the `for` loop.

It should be

```
 public static int Max(int[] window){
    //assume length of array window > 0

    int Max = window[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < window.length; i++){
        if (window[i] > Max) {
            Max = window[i];
        }
    }
    return Max;
}
```

It doesn't compile because it is possible to get to the end of the method without anything being returned. If the length of the array is `0` or `1` the loop will not be entered and the `return` not executed.